# Knockout ViewModel base class, Javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, knockout.js, prototype

I have been using Knockout.js for a lot of projects lately, and I am writing a lot of repetitive code. I would like to be able to define a `BaseViewModel` class and have my page-specific ViewModels inherit from it. I am a bit confused about how to do this is Javascript. Here is my basic `BaseViewModel`:

```
(function (ko, undefined) {
    ko.BaseViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observable([]);
        self.newItem = {};
        self.dirtyItems = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.items().filter(function (item) {
                return item.dirtyFlag.isDirty();
            });
        });
        self.isDirty = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.dirtyItems().length > 0;
        });
        self.load = function () { }
    };
}(ko));
```

I would like to be able to list signatures for methods like `load` in the `BaseViewModel` and then give them definitions in the inheriting ViewModel. Is any of this possible? I have found a few solutions online but they all rely on defining functions/classes to make the inheritance work.

Comment: why are you passing `undefined` into the function?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/158376/90240

Comment: Huh, never seen that before. I've also never run into the case where not doing that causes a bug, and he doesn't explain what that case is.

Comment: It is a defensive technique if you are writing code to be consumed by others.  It is possible to re-define the `undefined` symbol.  Declaring a function parameter `undefined` and then not passing any value for that argument is a technique to capture the actual `undefined` value even if someone has redefined the symbol.  As it happens, it also lets your JS minimizer minimize your usages of `undefined` since it is now just a local variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783510/javascript-how-dangerous-is-it-really-to-assume-undefined-is-not-overwritten

Comment: I didn't look at the other stackoverflow posts but the case of `undefined` not being `undefined` is an ES3 phenomenon that is not an issue anymore...but a lot of the libraries out there had to worry about it when they started, so they pass it in, and it became sort of a tradition, I suppose.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since your `BaseViewModel` is just adding all of the properties/methods to `this` (and not using prototype) then it is pretty easy:

In your new view models, just call `BaseViewModel`:

```
var MyVM = function () {
    var self = this;
    ko.BaseViewModel.call(self);

    self.somethingElse = ko.observable();
    self.itemCount = ko.computed(function() { return self.items().length; });
    self.items([1, 2, 3]); 
};


// ...
var vm = new MyVM();
```

Comment: Well that is way easier than I was expecting. Now I just need to figure out how that works!

Comment: The `ko.BaseViewModel.call(self)` line is the same as doing `:base()` in c#, right?

Comment: @theyshookhands Yes, it is the same as a `:base()` call. The `ViewModel.prototype = new BaseViewModel()` is the same as `Class : SubClass` in c#.

Comment: @theyshookhands - read about [Function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).  It allows you to call any function and supply the `this` value to use.  In this example, `BaseViewModel` is just being used as a helper function to initialize your viewmodel.  We are not *really* doing inheritance.  Things gets slightly more interesting when you start using prototype, which is JavaScript's mechanism for doing inheritance.

Comment: What is the difference in doing `ko.BaseViewModel.call(self)` vs `ko.utils.extend(self, new BaseViewModel(item))`, as seen here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14968058/251614

Comment: @Homer The `extend` technique allocates a new object (BaseViewModel), then copies the properties over to your subclass object and throws away the `BaseViewModel` object.  So a wasted allocation.  But more importantly, if `BaseViewModel` defines some functions or computeds that reference `self`, they will be referring to the thrown away object instead of your subclass instance, so the `extend` technique can actually lead to some subtle and hard to identify bugs.

Answer (score 10):

Javascript inheritance is done in two pieces. The first is in the constructor, and the second is on the prototype (which you aren't using, so you could skip).

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
    BaseViewModel.call(this);
};
//you only need to do this if you are adding prototype properties
ViewModel.prototype = new BaseViewModel();
```

To your last point, about overriding `load`, its no different that putting a `load` function on your viewmodel normally. Javascript allows you to override any objects properties with anything, there are no special steps here.

Here is a [fiddle demonstrating](http://jsfiddle.net/EUjJt/1/) the inheritance.

Comment: If you only need to worry about supporting modern browsers, you can replace that last line with `Viewmodel.prototype = Object.create(BaseViewModel.prototype);` and avoid some thorny issues with any undesired effects of calling `BaseViewModel` in this way.

Comment: And it's easy to shim `Object.create` in older browsers: `var objCreate = Object.create || function(o) { function F(){}; F.prototype = o; return new F(); };`