# Knockout JS base view model shared across all view models

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm working my way through learning Knockout JS and have come to a conclusion that I need to have a base view model that is shared across other view models.  This base view model needs to contain data and functionality that is common and used across pages in my jQuery Mobile application.  For example, each page has a pop-out panel containing site navigation.  Each page in the mobile app has the same panel, so I do not want to duplicate functions for do navigation for each page.  I'm using a Knockout JS template to construct the panel for each page.  The base view model also contains data used on each page.  So, I did some research and found this ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16570312/418549)):

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
    BaseViewModel.call(this);
};

ViewModel.prototype = new BaseViewModel();
```

I implemented the above approach like this:

```
myApp.BaseViewModel = function ()
{
    alert('foo');
    var self = this;
    self.CurrentPurchaseOrder = ko.observable(new PurchaseOrder());    
    self.OpenPanel = function (){..};
    self.ClosePanel = function (){..};
    self.LogOut = function (){..};
    self.GoHome = function (){..};
    self.CreateNewPurchaseOrderModal = function (){..};
    self.LoadInProgressPurchaseOrders = function (){..};
    self.LoadSubmittedPurchaseOrders = function (){..};
};

myApp.HomeViewModel = function ()
{
    var self = this;
    myApp.BaseViewModel.call(self);
    self.UserModel = ko.observable(new UserModel());    
};

myApp.PurchaseOrderListViewModel = function ()
{
    var self = this;
    myApp.BaseViewModel.call(self);
    self.PurchaseOrderList = ko.observableArray([]);
};

var baseViewModel = new myApp.BaseViewModel();
myApp.HomeViewModel.prototype = baseViewModel;
myApp.PurchaseOrderListViewModel.prototype = baseViewModel;
```

When I open the mobile app, I'm presented with multiple alert messages each displaying 'foo' (one for each view model extending baseViewModel).  I also noticed self.CurrentPurchaseOrder in base view model has different data for each page indicating that each page's view model is not sharing the same base view model.

I removed myApp.BaseViewModel.call(self) from each child view model and reran the mobile app and only receive 1 'foo' alert message.  After interacting with the app, self.CurrentPurchaseOrder in base view model has the same data across all pages which is what I need.

So, I'm not sure the purpose of myApp.BaseViewModel.call(self) in each child view model.  After removing it in each child view model, all pages shared the same data and each page still had access to the methods in the base class.  What's the purpose of myApp.BaseViewModel.call(self)?

Comment: I don't fully understand - you wrote myApp.BaseViewModel.call(self) but you are asking us what is the purpose of it?  What did you add it for?

Comment: Doing the `myApp.BaseViewModel.call(self)` call will call your base view model's constructor function, but with the value of `this` set to the new instance (object) of one of your other view models.  So, all of the observables created in BaseViewModel will get added to the current object that you are creating.

Comment: I added myApp.BaseViewModel.call(self) following the pattern I found in the link I noted.  When I removed myApp.BaseViewModel.call(self) from each child view model, I'm getting the behavior I want in that the data and the functions in BaseViewModel are available in each child view model.  I'm trying to understand the purpose of myApp.BaseViewModel.call(self).

Comment: I guess since I'm getting the behavior I need, then I'm good to go.

Comment: RP-Niemeyer - after removing myApp.BaseViewModel.call(self) from each child, my observables in my base class still work.

Comment: @TomSchreck you need to see my blog posts. I have provided a solution for the same problem. [This](http://raheelshan.wordpress.com/2014/04/10/with-binding-magic-writing-single-page-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-knockoutjs/) and [this](http://raheelshan.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/knockoutjs-make-parent-and-child-structure-in-your-app/)